# stm8tool is not available for you operating system (ubuntu OS)

Tags: installation

I have tried to  add STM8 to arduino by [this](https://tenbaht.github.io/sduino/) instruction :

but i have this error:

[image]

also my system is :

```
so@so-notebook:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Also googled the :

[**stm8tool is not available for you operating system**](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk03Zxf62_UH3iXANzkz5ImII-__6Zg%3A1594909453538&ei=DWMQX-63IMq0kgWB-YOwCg&q=stm8tool%20is%20not%20available%20for%20you%20operating%20system&oq=stm8tool%20is%20not%20available%20for%20you%20operating%20system&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIECCMQJ1CCH1iCH2C9IGgAcAB4AIABhQKIAYUCkgEDMi0xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiu8rTb_NHqAhVKmqQKHYH8AKYQ4dUDCAw&uact=5)

but don't find any result to solve ...

**Update:**

based of comments :

```
so@so-notebook:~$ uname -a
Linux so-notebook 5.6.9-050609-generic #202005051753 SMP Tue May 5 22:00:17 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please also post the output of `uname -a`

Comment: All seems fine on 20.04 to me... The content of the json file looks fine too.